# What do you call course literature that you can choose?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What do you call literature that a student may choose to study for a certain course. I don't mean optional literature, or reference material, but rather a selection of books, articles etc from which the student **must** choose a given number of texts, but they still get to choose **within** that selection. Do you say that it is *elective*? *Electable*? What? And, while I'm at it, which is the better choice of *course literature* and *course reading* for the books etc that you need to study for a course at the university? (Or should it be something else entirely?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific adjectives that do what you're asking.
Of the two you suggest: "elective" would tend to refer to the course as a whole, not the reading material; and "electable" means something entirely different.

Exactly which word or words *would* fit really depends on the broader context. A couple of examples:

> For my English literature course, I have to choose four texts from the reading list of ten.

> Spanish Level 2 - *Cervantes* -- begins next Tuesday. I will focus on the first volume of *Don Quixote*, but for final exam purposes you will also be required to discuss your own choice of three of the twelve *Novelas ejemplares*.

As to the term for such material: there are many. Both of yours -- "course literature" and "course reading" -- could work, although in the case of a technical topic (science, engineering), "literature" might not be used. Others include, "reading list", "book list", "required and suggested reading", and so on.

Comment: I don't think the word item is so great here.

Comment: Yeah, there's probably something better. Got a suggestion?

Comment: choice of text or texts

Comment: "I have to choose four *choices of text* from the reading list of ten."??? 

Comment: Ah, no, I think I gotcha. Fixed. Better?

Comment: A student has to choose **four texts from a reading list**. A student has **a choice of four texts from a reading list**. From **a** reading list of ten books or texts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Literature Courses:

- Required Courses
- Elective Courses

Reading List for a course

- reading list with choice of 5 texts [for example]
- choice of five texts from the reading list
- required reading [list]
- optional reading [list]

You have a choice or choose some number of texts or works from some list.